# Division tag header

Tags: html, css

I want this *hello world* on the header section which I made using `div` but when i use `p` tag to write it in division the text doesn't appear in the header section I made instead it is appearing below it.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkvmz.png)

Stylesheet Code:

```html
body{
 background-image: url("back.jpg");
}

.main{
 height:100%;
 width:1100px;
 margin-left:6%;
 background-color:white;
}
.header{
 height:20%;
 width:1100px;
 background-image: url("head.jpg")
}
.logo{
 height:100%;
 width:250px;
 background-image: url("head.jpg");
 float:left;
}
.menu{height:7%;
 width:1100px;
 background-color:gray;
}
.content{
 height:63%;
 width:1100px;
}

.footer{height:10%;
 width:1100px;
 background-color:maroon;
}
#logoimage{
  height:100%;
}
h1{
 color:white;
}
```

HTML Webpage Code

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css">
  <title></title> 
  
 </head>
 
 <div class="main">
   <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
     <img src="logo.png" alt="Sorry for the inconvenience" id="logoimage">
     <h1> Hello World </h1>
    </div><!--Logo ends here-->
   </div><!--Header ends here-->
    <div class="menu">
   </div><!--Menu bar ends here-->
   <div class="content">
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
   </div><!--Footer ends here-->
 </div><!--Body ends here-->
 
 
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Hello World` does show up on the page... the reason why you cannot see it, is because your font color is set to white, here:

```
h1{
    color:white;
}
```

Change that to some other color and you should be able to see it [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58xjwo1w/).

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58xjwo1w/1/) with *Hello World* in `p` tag

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i was able to figure my problem out. Thank you @Rushikumar for the the reply actually i was not able to show my hello world inside the header section for the div i made i was inserting the text inside the the logo section of the div. Sorry because of this silly mistake i made a forum post.